# Why can't I add a register_post_type or taxonomy within a class object?

Tags: wordpress

Here is the code:

```
<?php  

// (wp_plugin_dir/My_plugin/index.php) 
class interface{
    __construct(){
    $this->get_commerce();
    }

}

$interface = new interface();

// (wp_plugin_dir/My_plugin/commerce/commerce.php) 

    class commerce{
        __construct(){
            $this->register_post_types();
        }

        function register_post_types(){
            $args = array( 'public' => true, 'label' => 'Books' );
            register_post_type( 'book', $args );
        }
    }


}
?>
```

It doesn't register the post type for some reason? But when I put the same register_post_type function in index.php, it works fine

Comment: This was my exact question (answer worked). And why I continue to use SO everyday.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably trying to run the register BEFORE it initializes. Just hook that method of your class to the init hook (or anything that runs after it, like theme_setup) and you're good to go.